# Wordpress function enable Iframe forbackend

Tags: wordpress, iframe

In Wordpress version <6.0 I was able to load admin screens via an Iframe in an external website by adding these lines to the functions.php

remove_action( 'login_init',          'send_frame_options_header',     10, 0 );
remove_action( 'admin_init',           'send_frame_options_header',    10, 0 );

However since WP 6.0 it is not working anymore. How can I get this to work again?

Comment: Any information as to why it isn't working? Any logs or error output for us to see?

Comment: This is the Firefox message:

To protect your security, www.diginomad.nl will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.

This is the

Comment: Same here, I don't know what is wrong?